# Finding both variables in a two component pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, uipickerview

I can't find anywhere that explains how to get the info from both components of a pickerView.  Right now all it does is put the String from the last moved component into the test label.  I don't really need them to be in outlets but just access to them.  I also would like to use the array format that I commented out.

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemPickerView: UIPickerView!

var pickerViewArray = [["Items", "Key", "Rock"], ["Action", "Turn", "Hit"]]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerViewArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerViewArray[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerViewArray[component][row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    itemSelected = pickerViewArray[component][row]
    pickerOutletTest.text = itemSelected
}

@IBOutlet weak var pickerOutletTest: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your didSelectRow method with below one.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     pickerOutletTest.text = pickerViewArray[0][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] + " " + pickerViewArray[1][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This answer seemed more straight forward and with a little messing around I made it work for my level of understanding.  I broke it in to this         
         picker1 = pickerViewArray[0] [pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] + " "
        picker2 = pickerViewArray[1] [pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)] + " "

Comment: Thank you. Happy coding.

Comment: I just want to point out an issue I had with the way I used this.  I wanted to compare the picker view values to other values.  I found that with the quotation marks " " that create a space behind my word so I needed to use this to compare "dogs ".  To fix that I just closed up the quotation marks "".

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of the selected items in all components with

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let selectedItems = (0..<pickerViewArray.count).map{  pickerViewArray[$0][pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: $0)]}
    print(selectedItems)
}
```

The `map`ping of the component indices to their selected values is a abbreviated form of

```
var selectedItems = [String]()
for component in 0..<pickerViewArray.count {
    let selectedRow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: component)
    selectedItems.append(pickerViewArray[component][selectedRow])
}
```

Comment: I like this and will probably change to it once I fully understand whats going on. But at the moment it is over my head.